# How to refresh listview using base adapter in android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am trying to refresh listview after sorting names, where data sorting actually works, but list could not refreshed. Here, if i touch listview then shows the sorting data, but when i click sorting button, it does not works only show blank data.

I have done in program, like this

```
String[] names = new String[] { "Honeycomb", "Donut", "Eclair", "Cupcake", "IceCream Sandwich", "Froyo", "Gingerbread" };

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
nameAdapter= new MyBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(names));
System.out.println(" no sort="+Arrays.asList(names));
bsort.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(names));
System.out.println("sort "+Arrays.asList(names));
            //nameAdapter= new MyBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(names));
            //listView.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
            nameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

logcat

```
01-19 15:40:08.971: I/System.out(22343):  no sort=[Honeycomb, Donut, Eclair, Cupcake, IceCream Sandwich, Froyo, Gingerbread]
01-19 15:40:09.158: E/Surface(22343): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb884c720
01-19 15:40:09.159: D/OpenGLRenderer(22343): endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb886bd70 (ListView) with handle 0xb8933368
01-19 15:40:15.002: I/System.out(22343): sort [Cupcake, Donut, Eclair, Froyo, Gingerbread, Honeycomb, IceCream Sandwich]
```

**Only problem is I couldnot refresh or update listview, when button bsort is click**. When i first time bsort click, sorting data but unable to listview refresh, data are showing non sorted, but when i click listview then sorted data are shown in listview.

Is there is something wrong, with this code.

Comment: Try : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5092426/1277178

Answer (score 0):

You're creating Lists in 2 places in your code:

```
nameAdapter= new MyBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(names));

Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(names));
```

so each time you click you create another List, then you sort it, but it has no effect on the 1st list you passed to the constructor. Create only 1 list, and use it in both places:

```
List list = Arrays.asList(names);
nameAdapter= new MyBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);

Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: You left out the notifydatasetchanged. That is a key piece to this as well.